# Down Convert DWORD to BYTE, Assembly 32 bits

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32, masm32

I would like to down convert Dword to Byte so that I can store it to a textfile in readable text by `call WriteToFile`. How can I do it?

```
 .386     
 .model flat, stdcall  
 INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
 .stack 4096  

 .Data
 total         DWORD  ?      ;total is a variable which holding a math calc output
 totalTXT       BYTE  ?      ;totalTXT would be the output in String value.
```

Here is where i try to downcast the conversion

```
 xor eax, eax
 mov eax,  total
 mov totalTXT, al
```

I need totalTXT in byte so I can store into file as text. But After debugging, my textfile become empty.

```
WRITE_TO_FILE:                 ;assume file is successfully opened

 mov eax,fileHandle 
 mov edx, OFFSET   totalTXT          
 mov ecx, LENGTHOF totalTXT   
 call WriteToFile
 call CloseFile
```

Comment: That *should* be writing one byte, the low byte of the binary integer you loaded from `total`.  (Not converted to ASCII or anything, but the file size should be 1, not 0).  But anyway, [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) explains how to convert an integer to an ASCII decimal string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DWORD memory variable may contain four ASCII characters, a pointer, a number encoded as signed or unsigned binary number, floating-point number, binary-coded decimal number etc.
If you want to store its contents in the form of a human-readable text, you'll need to convert it first.

Also note that one byte reserved by `totalTXT` is not enough for numbers above 9.
It should be declared as `totalTXT BYTE 12 DUP (?)` or whatever size is you `total` converted to.

As [Peter Cordes says in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66766633/how-do-i-modify-this-code-to-output-like-6-is-within-the-range-3-to-15-instead-o#comment118026680_66766633), *Irvine32 has `WriteDec` and `WriteInt` functions to print a binary integer from EAX, like printf %u or %d.*